# Trouble solving the geodesic equation?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

I am working through Moore's "General Relativity Workbook" and am stuck on a problem (8.4.2). I believe I am missing something quite trivial, but I can't figure it out.  Any help is appreciated.

The metric is (coordinates p,q):
$$g_{\mu\nu}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1+4c^2p^2 & 2cp\\
2cp & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

I am to verify that the geodesic equation
$$0=\frac{d}{ds}\left(g_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^\beta}{ds}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\partial_{\alpha}g_{\mu\nu}\frac{dx^\mu}{ds}\frac{dx^\nu}{ds}$$
Reduces, when $\alpha=q$, to
$$0=2cp\frac{d^2p}{ds^2}+2c\left(\frac{dp}{ds}\right)^2+\frac{d^2q}{ds^2}$$
I don't see where the $2c\left(\frac{dp}{ds}\right)^2$ term is coming from.  As I see things,
$\partial_{q}g_{\mu\nu}=0$ for all $\mu, \nu$.  So the only relevant term is $$\frac{d}{ds}\left(g_{\alpha\beta}\frac{dx^\beta}{ds}\right)=\frac{d}{ds}\left(g_{q\beta}\frac{dx^\beta}{ds}\right)=\frac{d}{ds}\left(g_{qp}\frac{dx^p}{ds}+g_{qq}\frac{dx^q}{ds}\right)=\frac{d}{ds}\left(g_{qp}\frac{dp}{ds}\right)+\frac{d}{ds}\left(g_{qq}\frac{dq}{ds}\right)=\frac{d}{ds}\left(2cp\frac{dp}{ds}\right)+\frac{d}{ds}\left((1)\frac{dq}{ds}\right)=2cp\frac{d^2p}{ds^2}+\frac{d^2q}{ds^2}$$

What have I missed here?

Comment: To adjust the parentheses size to their content you must  use  `\left(  \right)` instead of `(  )`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last step, you also have to derive $p$ with respect to $s$, so

$$...=\frac{d}{ds}\Big(2cp\frac{dp}{ds}\Big)+\frac{d}{ds}\Big(\frac{dq}{ds}\Big)=2c\Big(\frac{dp}{ds}\Big)^2+2cp\frac{d^2p}{ds^2}+\frac{d^2q}{ds^2}.$$

Comment: yes this is where I am getting hung up. Where is this term coming from?  Is it a result of the product rule being applied to $2cp$?  But neither $c$ nor $p$ depend on $s$, so shouldn't the derivative be 0?

Comment: Yes, it is a result of the product rule. Geodesics are parameterized curves $x^\mu=x^\mu(s)$, where $x^\mu$ are coordinates and $s$ the parameter.